# How to get the id using alpine @click

Tags: alpine-linux, alpine.js

I have this url tag

```html
<a id="day-{{$index+1}}"
  @click="console.log($event.target.getAttribute('id'))"
           <p class="uppercase font-Lato">
              Day {{$index+1}}
           </p>
</a>
```

but if I click on the url I get "undefined" because it will try to log the child element id, I want to get the "a" element id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `{{$index+1}}` is server side code.
You do not need to do a getAttribute() on the `$event.target` ...
You are looking for the `.parentNode`

```
<a id="day-{{$index+1}}"
  @click="console.log($event.target.parentNode.id)"
           <p class="uppercase font-Lato">
              Day {{$index+1}}
           </p>
</a>
```

I find it useful to console.log the entire object and then look at the details of the object in the console to find the "attributes" I'm looking for.